# Windows batch command(s) to read first line from text file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How can I read the first line from a text file using a Windows batch file? Since the file is large I only want to deal with the first line.

Comment: Try GNU32 "head" utility. Don't think what you are after will be easily accomplished by just DOS Batch.

Comment: @Nasir , Can't it be done with an inbuilt command?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Here's a general-purpose batch file to print the top `n` lines from a file like the GNU `head` utility, instead of just a single line.

```
@echo off

if [%1] == [] goto usage
if [%2] == [] goto usage

call :print_head %1 %2
goto :eof

REM
REM print_head
REM Prints the first non-blank %1 lines in the file %2.
REM
:print_head
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a counter=0

for /f ^"usebackq^ eol^=^

^ delims^=^" %%a in (%2) do (
        if "!counter!"=="%1" goto :eof
        echo %%a
        set /a counter+=1
)

goto :eof

:usage
echo Usage: head.bat COUNT FILENAME
```

For example:

```
Z:\>head 1 "test file.c"
; this is line 1

Z:\>head 3 "test file.c"
; this is line 1
    this is line 2
line 3 right here
```

It does not currently count blank lines.  It is also subject to the batch-file line-length restriction of 8 KB.

Comment: FYI: "GOTO :EOF" That's a special label that will exit the script without having to define a special ":exit" label. It's also useful when defining subroutines in the batch ( what's that you say? subroutines? Yep )

Comment: This seems to bomb out on my several GB text files... On one file it gave me an "Out of Memory" error when trying to return 10 lines, on the other file it just returned a single blank line when asking it to return 10 lines.  Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: @Dan - How long are the lines? FOR /F "ignores" lines longer than 8191 bytes. But I wonder if the "Out of Memory" error arises if it encounters a really long line.

Comment: @StephanMuller - See my comment to Dan above

Comment: As written, this answer will ignore empty lines. It will also ignore lines that begin with a semicolon `;`, the default FOR /F EOL character. If asking for 10 lines, then it will print the first 10 lines that are not empty and do not begin with `;`.

Comment: @indiv `for /f "usebackq eol= delims="` will not disable the `EOL` character it will set it to `<SPACE>`. A solution to disable the EOL is at [SO: Concatenate two strings...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9419215/463115)

Comment: @Dan: is this the same Dan from GalaxyLegion?

Answer (score 247):

uh?
imo this is much simpler

```
  set /p texte=< file.txt  
  echo %texte%
```

Comment: +1, This is the best when it works :-) It has following limits 1) Max line length of 1021 bytes, not including EOL. 2) The file must use Windows style EOL of CarriageReturn LineFeed. 3) Trailing control characters will be stripped from the line

Comment: Also, texte should be explicitly undefined prior to reading the file just in case 1st line is blank.

Comment: [Here](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php) are some extra tips for trimming the string. `echo %texte:~3%` for example will skip the first three chars. That is usefully when you are reading an UTF-8 file with BOM.

Comment: This is not working. `The syntax of the command is incorrect.` First line was `#include <iostream>`. So, apparently, `<` and `>` symbol break this... Not the most robust solution.

Answer (score 26):

Uh you guys...

```
C:\>findstr /n . c:\boot.ini | findstr ^1:

1:[boot loader]

C:\>findstr /n . c:\boot.ini | findstr ^3:

3:default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINNT

C:\>
```

Comment: If the file has more than 11 lines it will print more than the first, like: 1:, 11:, 21:, etc...

Comment: Good catch Cesar! I always try to avoid quotes because they annoy me, but in this case it was a bad idea. To fix, change to `findstr "^1:"` and gain the warmth and protection of double quotes. Or, if you despise quotes like me and want to live dangerously, use `findstr /b 1:`

Comment: if you want it without quotes and without /b option then just escape the caret: `findstr ^^1`.

Comment: Great hint dbenham, the escaping in cmd always escapes me. By the way, please don't use this method for large files, it actually reads the entire file and is very inefficient. My only criteria for this solution were A) It should be a single line B) It should be easy to remember or recreate from memory and type, not copy-paste C) No external tools. The `set /p` solution is far more efficient for large files.

Comment: Also, it prepends the line number to the line of text you actually want! Therefore not so useful when you just needed the text.

Comment: `findstr /n . downing.txt | findstr ^^1` :prints lines starting with 1 eg. 1, 11, 12, 13.
`findstr /n . downing.txt | findstr ^^1:` :prints 1st line only
`findstr /n . downing.txt | findstr ^1:` :prints lines containing 1 eg. 1, 11, 21, 31

Comment: I just changed ^1: to :1: and it worked. Neither double quotes nor double ^^ worked for me

Answer (score 13):

You might give this a try:

```
@echo off

for /f %%a in (sample.txt) do (
  echo %%a
  exit /b
)
```

**edit**
Or, say you have four columns of data and want from the 5th row down to the bottom, try this:

```
@echo off

for /f "skip=4 tokens=1-4" %%a in (junkl.txt) do (
  echo %%a %%b %%c %%d
)
```

Comment: This gave me the clue I needed but was not quite right. Not sure what the proper procedure was but I incorporated this solution into the final solution. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130116#130209

Comment: This solution's problem is that it delimits on space instead of newline, and you can't have a filename with spaces. You can fix these issues with the delims and usebackq options in the for loop.

Comment: Worked for me, but I had to add `"delims="` to print out full folder names together with spaces.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to thetalkingwalnut with answer [Windows batch command(s) to read first line from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130116/dos-batch-commands-to-read-first-line-from-text-file#130154) I came up with the following solution:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type sample.txt') do (
echo %%a
exit /b
)
```

Answer (score 5):

`powershell Get-Content file.txt -Head 1`

This one is much quicker than the other powershell examples above, where the full file is read.

Answer (score 4):

Slightly building upon the answers of other people.  Now allowing you to specify the file you want to read from and the variable you want the result put into:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%x in (%2) do (
set %1=%%x
exit /b
)
```

This means you can use the above like this (assuming you called it getline.bat)

```
c:\> dir > test-file
c:\> getline variable test-file
c:\> set variable  
variable= Volume in drive C has no label.
```

Answer (score 3):

One liner, useful for stdout redirect with ">":

```
@for /f %%i in ('type yourfile.txt') do @echo %%i & exit
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set firstLine=1
for /f "delims=" %%i in (yourfilename.txt) do (
    if !firstLine!==1 echo %%i
    set firstLine=0
)
endlocal
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround using `powershell`:

```
powershell (Get-Content file.txt)[0]
```

(You can easily read also a range of lines with `powershell (Get-Content file.txt)[0..3]`)

If you need to set a variable inside a batch script as the first line of `file.txt` you may use:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`powershell ^(Get-Content file.txt^)[0]`) do (set "head=%%a")
```

To test it create a text file `test.txt` with at least a couple of lines and in the same folder run the following batch file (give to the file the `.bat` extension):

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`powershell ^(Get-Content test.txt^)[0]`) do (set "head=%%a")
echo Hello
echo %head%
echo End
pause
```

In the command prompt window that will open, provided that the content of first line of `test.txt` is `line 1`, you will see

```
Hello
line 1
End
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Powershell is very slow

Comment: @CyclingDave I don't know how you tested it, but it works for me under Windows 11.  See the test I added in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

To cicle a file (`file1.txt`, `file1[1].txt`, `file1[2].txt`, etc.):

```
START/WAIT C:\LAERCIO\DELPHI\CICLADOR\dprCiclador.exe C:\LAERCIUM\Ciclavel.txt

rem set/p ciclo=< C:\LAERCIUM\Ciclavel.txt:
set/p ciclo=< C:\LAERCIUM\Ciclavel.txt

rem echo %ciclo%:
echo %ciclo%
```

And it's running.

Comment: The explanation for this is: `set /p` asks through a prompt; however with file redirection `<` it immediately gets the contents of the file at the prompt; and as the first line ends with a line ending, at that point the prompt stops reading, and thus stores just the first line in the variable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the `EXIT /B` solutions, when more realistically inside a batch file as just one part of it is the following. There is no subsequent processing within the said batch file after the `EXIT /B`. Usually there is much more to batches than just the one, limited task.

To counter that problem:

```
@echo off & setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set myfile_=C:\_D\TEST\My test file.txt
set FirstLine=
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%myfile_%"') do (
  if not defined FirstLine set FirstLine=%%i)
echo FirstLine=%FirstLine%
endlocal & goto :EOF
```

(However, the so-called poison characters will still be a problem.)

More on the subject of getting a particular line with batch commands:

> How do I get the n'th, the first and the last line of a text file?"
>   http://www.netikka.net/tsneti/info/tscmd023.htm

**[Added 28-Aug-2012]** One can also have:

```
@echo off & setlocal enableextensions
set myfile_=C:\_D\TEST\My test file.txt
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (
  'type "%myfile_%"') do (
    set FirstLine=%%a& goto _ExitForLoop)
:_ExitForLoop
echo FirstLine=%FirstLine%
endlocal & goto :EOF
```

Comment: The set /p texte=< file.txt is probably the niftiest solution that has been presented. In this thread by @Spaceballs. In general, I would write set /p "texte"=<"file.txt" but that is beside the point. Note that even this solution is prone to the poison character problems, i.e. may fail depending on what the file.txt contains.

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in (filename.txt) do (
if 1==1 (
set first_line=%%i
echo !first_line!
goto :eof
))
```

Comment: I would recommend using a .bat file ONLY as a last resort. If it all possible, always try to use a "real" scripting language: Powershell, WSH, Python ... ANYTHING but .bat files.

Comment: Batch isn't *that* bad (when you know, what you do; same as with every other language). hhay: your code isn't working.

Comment: because you don't use [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)

Comment: @paulsm4: What's wrong with batch files? It works on all flavors of Windows, and has a unique feature called delayedexpansion, allowing magic to happen without installing 3rd party software, as long as you understand it. Did you know you could TCP/IP with DOS & batch files long before Powershell & dotNet?

Answer (score 0):

Note, the batch file approaches will be limited to the line limit for the DOS command processor - see [What is the command line length limit?](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/10/56028.aspx).

So if trying to process a file that has any lines more that **8192** characters the script will just skip them as the value can't be held.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows PowerShell below cmd can be used to get the first line and replace it with a static value

```
powershell -Command "(gc txt1.txt) -replace (gc txt1.txt)[0], 'This is the first line' | Out-File -encoding ASCII txt1.txt"
```

Reference

---

[How can you find and replace text in a file using the Windows command-line environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir)

Answer (score -1):

Print *1st line only* (no need to read entire file):

```
set /p a=< file.txt & echo !a!
```

To print one line at a time; user to press a key for next line:
(After printing required lines, press Ctrl+C to stop.)

```
for /f "delims=" %a in (downing.txt) do echo %a & pause>nul
```

To *print 1st n lines* (without user intervention):

```
type nul > tmp & fc tmp "%file%" /lb %n% /t | find /v "?" | more +2
```

Tested on Win 10 CMD.