# for /f closes cmd prompt immediately

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

When I open cmd.exe and type that first line and push ENTER, it works fine. When I input that other line and push ENTER, it closes immediately.

I can change ('a') to ('asdfgh') then same problem. or %q to %f same problem.

The difference is the /f, for some reason the FOR /F with ('......') causes cmd.exe to close.

This happens on one of my systems and not another

```
C:\>for %q in ('a') do echo %q   <ENTER>

C:\>echo 'a'
'a'

C:\>for /f %q in ('a') do echo %q <ENTER>
```

Comment: What version of Windows? It works for me in Windows 7 HP SP1. I mean, it doesn't terminate the CMD session but prints the error about `a` being a wrong command.

Comment: XP SP3. It shouldn't close the cmd prompt in any version of windows, but it does on this machine.

Comment: Looks like the problem is not unknown in these quarters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261296/batch-closes-prematurely-on-a-for-f-command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This guy seems to have solved a very similar problem successfully:

[for /f closes cmd window immediately](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=504)

The problem in that case turned out to have to do with the `COMSPEC` environment variable, it being incorrectly set initially, as it seems. The guy applied logging out of the Windows account and back in.

Comment: COMSPEC did get listed when doing SET<ENTER>
So, I opened the environment variables window, and saw COMSPEC was not listed under user or system variables. I added it to System Variables, started a command prompt, and it seems to work fine.

Comment: +1 That was really a brilliant find. I wasn't expecting anybody to be able to answer it.

Comment: That question you mentioned in your comment to my question, has 2200 views, and nobody got it. You should get a medal!

Comment: Oddly the title for that thread on ss64.org forum , apart from one char, is identical character for character to mine! His was more accurate though for not including a question mark(the one char difference), I think i'll remove my question mark!

Comment: @barlop: It is fascinating how both you and Google think that 'prompt' and 'window' are the same word. :) I googled for `"for /f" closes command prompt`, and in the results the word `window` was highlighted in bold just as well as `prompt`. Other than that, I agree that the coincidence you've mentioned is really striking.

Comment: oh, actually i said cmd prompt he said cmd window.

Answer (score 0):

Add a paranthesis "(", like this:

```
for %q in ('a') do (
```

It will prompt you with a "More?" in the following lines until you decide to close your for block with a ")"

Comment: C:\>for /f %f in ('echo abc') do ( <ENTER>
More? echo hello <ENTER>
More? echo hello <ENTER>
More? )    <-- so i've hit ) then I hit ENTER and the cmd prompt suddenly closes.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the help for 'FOR' ('FOR /?'), you can see that the '/F' option is for parsing file input and has the following options:

```
FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN (file-set) DO command [command-parameters]
FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ("string") DO command [command-parameters]
FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ('command') DO command [command-parameters]
```

Note that last entry... a single-quoted value is treated as a command to run, and the output of that command is what 'FOR' is parsing.

Perhaps you have an 'a' command/executable on one machine, but not on the other?

You should only be using the '/F' flag if you specifically want the behavior that '/F' supplies.

Comment: I said I tried changing a to asdf, same problem. In those cases it should say no such program/"'adsf' is not recognized as an internal or external command". It still shouldn't close. This line also causes the cmd prompt to close C:\>for /f %f in ('echo asdf') do set ttt=%f      This is a problem on one machine and not another.

Comment: Fair enough... and it looks like the actual problem (mis-set COMSPEC) was a real doozy.  Nonetheless, using--or not using--'/F' changes the semantic meaning of the 'FOR'.  You shouldn't expect to be able to interchange them.  (Although you *should* be able to expect it not to crash. :-) )

Comment: I know what /F does. My example was to demonstrate the problem, by showing a symptom, with the advantage of it being a simple example. I didn't say comspec was mis-set, that looks like something Andriy M said most probably wrongly since his source didn't say it was mis-set. It was just as I said. It may well have had the correct value when it came up from SET<ENTER>, i'd bet it did, but it needed to be set in the environment variables window / that place in the registry.