# Batch command to take only first line from input

Tags: batch-file

I'm looking for a DOS batch program that takes a file:

```
First input line
Second input line
Third input line...
```

And outputs "First input line"

Comment: See duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130116/dos-batch-commands-to-read-first-line-from-text-file

Comment: @ire_and_curses - thanks, voted to close.

Answer (score 14):

you can just get the first line like this

```
set /p firstline=<file
echo %firstline%
```

Comment: That’s because the echo will only show the first line; using it line `if "%firstline%"=="foo"` will use all of it…

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you mean the Windows `cmd` interpreter (I'd be surprised if you really *were* still using DOS), the following script will do what you want:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set first=1
for /f "delims=" %%i in (infile.txt) do (
    if !first!==1 echo %%i
    set first=0
)
endlocal
```

With an input file of `infile.txt` as:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

this will output:

```
line 1
```

This will still *process* all the lines, it just won't print those beyond line 1. If you want to actually stop processing, use something like:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in (infile.txt) do (
    echo %%i
    goto :endfor
)
:endfor
endlocal
```

Or you could just go get your hands on [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) and use the `head` program. That's what I'd do. But, if that's not an option (some workplaces don't allow it), you can create a similar cmd file in Windows itself as follows (`winhead.cmd`):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

if x%1x==xx goto :usage
if x%2x==xx goto :usage

set /a "linenum = 0"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (%1) do (
    if !linenum! geq %2 goto :break1
    echo %%i
    set /a "linenum = linenum + 1"
)
:break1
endlocal
goto :finish

:usage
echo.winhead ^<file^> ^<numlines^>
echo.   ^<file^>
echo.      is the file to process
echo.      (surround with double quotes if it contains spaces).
echo.   ^<numlines^>
echo.      is the number of lines to print from file start.
goto :finish

:finish
endlocal
```

Comment: Oh, you only need `for` if you either need all or the last input line. For getting the first line using `set /p` is much easier.

Comment: You can also avoid needing delayed expansion by testing for `first` with `if not defined first` and un-setting it after the first line.

Comment: Avoid needing it? Why? It's the best thing since sliced bread! Just about every one of my scripts starts with that setlocal line; it's brilliant.

Comment: Well, I avoid using it if I don't desperately need it as it still incurs some thinking when writing and reading a script as to where delayed expansion is necessary and when not.

Answer (score -2):

why not use the more +1 command via a pipe?

e.g.

type something | more +1

Comment: That displays everything **from** the first line, the OP needs **up until** the first line. See `more /?`: "+n -> Start displaying the first file at line n"