# How to get only the reply line of a ping test on Windows

Tags: windows, cmd, ping

Usually, when pinging a server IP address we have this in return:

```
Pinging <IP address> with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from <ip> : bytes=32 time=151 TTL=121
Reply from <ip> : bytes=32 time=151 TTL=121
Reply from <ip> : bytes=32 time=151 TTL=121
Reply from <ip> : bytes=32 time=151 TTL=121

Ping statistics for <IP address>:
packets: sent = 4, Received = 4, lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-secounds:
Minimum = 151ms, Maximum = 151 ms, Average = 151 ms
```

How do I get only the following line (only the reply line of one ping test) in return by a simple command in cmd.exe on Windows (whatever Windows language used)?

```
Reply from <IP address> : bytes=32 time=151 TTL=121
```

Maybe the simplest way is to display only the second line? How should this be done? Because I don't know how to do it on Windows.

Answer (score 23):

This may work more universally.

```
ping -n 1 <hostname/IP> | FIND "TTL="
```

Answer (score 5):

You can combine findstr command with the skip lines option of for:

```
C:\>ping 127.0.0.1 | for /f "skip=3 tokens=*" %a in ('findstr Reply') do @echo %a
```

Output is:

```
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
```

Change `%a` to `%%a` if writing a batch file.

Answer (score 3):

Well,

```
ping -n 1 <hostname/IP>
```

Will send only 1 ping request. And you should be able to find the reply line using none other than the `FIND` command.

So, something like this:

```
ping -n 1 <hostname/IP> | FIND "Reply"
```

**UPDATE**

I know the above works on an English, Windows 7 machine. I would assume that it would work for other localizations, but this may be an incorrect assumption.

**UPDATE 2**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516411/batch-command-to-take-only-first-line-from-input) seems to provide some insight. You may have to write the output of ping to a file (using the `>` output redirection pipe) and then use the commands in the answers to get only the second line.

Comment: It will not work for all versions of windows(those which have different language than english)

Comment: Interesting, terminal commands vary by localization? That strikes me as odd.

Comment: @ mjgpy3 : Yes. Language is a problem. Because result of windows ping tool changes when language of operating system changes. Google it and you will see I am right.

Comment: maybe displaying only the second line of the answer by a grep? But I don't know how to make it on cmd.exe.

Comment: @ mjgspy: I am looking for a direct command actually, like we can do easily on Linux. I do not want to create a file only for a ping.

Comment: @mastermind, I understand, I am sorry I was unable to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this with powershell... here is the code you can add to a script

```
$ping = new-object System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
$reply = $ping.send('127.0.0.1')
if ($reply.status -eq "Success"){
    [string]::Format("Reply from {0},time={1}",$reply.Address.ToString(),$reply.RoundtripTime)
    }else{
    $z = [system.net.dns]::gethostaddresses($hostname)[0].ipaddresstostring
    [string]::Format("FAIL,{0},{1}",$z,"***")
}
```

You can format the string in any format you want.

Comment: So if I understand well there is no direct commands for doing it like on Linux?

Comment: not that I know of... I have used this script snippet in the past with success.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple from within batch, but from command line... ugly is major understatement:

```
(for /f "skip=1 delims=" %F in ('ping -n 1 localhost') do @if not defined _A @echo %F&set _A=0) &set "_A="
```

But it does the trick, prints second line (whatever it will happen to contain) and skips the rest. You may change line it prints changing `skip=`.

If you have powershell available, you could simply do: (*yes I know it's not how pinging is supposed to be done in PS*): `powershell "ping -n 1 localhost | select -index 2"`. You may need to play with index, as on my (XP) laptop ping inserts addtional CR in each line, which has an effect of double - spacing output from PS.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, I couldn't get the FIND pipe to work in a powershell 5.1 shell. Feeling like this was all overly complicated, I thought if only I could grep the Reply line? I then found the powershell equivalent! I just used select-string on the first line matching 'Reply' which gave me the one line output I was looking for. So this worked very simply and easy for me.

```
ping -n 1 <hostname/IP> | select-string -pattern 'Reply'
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @wmz answer,

```
(for /f "skip=3 tokens=*" %F in ('ping -n 1 <hostname/IP>') do @if not defined _A @echo %F&set _A=0) &set "_A="
```

is ok as a one-liner not language dependent.
It will also give the result when no response is given (Timeout), where find and findstr will not.