# Java Version in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

My question, is extremely similar to the following SO question: [How to get Java Version from batch script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5675459/1168372)

In fact, it did **almost** solve my problem. The only difference is that I've to check the Java version based on %JAVA_HOME%, which the user is free to modify. The issue that I'm facing is with this code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

IF "%JAVA_HOME%"=="" (
    @ECHO Please set JAVA_HOME environment variable
    EXIT /B
) 

@echo "%JAVA_HOME%"

REM Checking JAVA_VERSION
SET JAVA_VERSION=
FOR /f "tokens=3" %%g in ('"%JAVA_HOME%"\bin\java -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "version"') do (
        SET "JAVA_VERSION=%%g"
)
```

%JAVA_HOME%% in my system points to "C:\Program Files\jdk1.7.0_25" (*notice the space in the path*)

Even with the quotes, I get the following error in command line:

> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Any idea as to how to solve this problem? (The comments to the aforementioned article also mentions this issue). I'm working on a Windows 7 machine

Answer (score 3):

```
FOR /f "tokens=3" %%g in ('"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "version"') do (
        SET "JAVA_VERSION=%%g"
)
```

Comment: Still get the same error. I had actually tried this as well. If I echo %JAVA_VERSION% after this, it shows that the variable has stored "-version" as its value

Comment: Maybe, but you doesn't get the error: `'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`.

Comment: I do the same error Endoro. It's just I added one more echo statement after the for to see if JAVA_VERSION comes empty or not. That's where it shows "-version" as the value for this variable. This is not related to my actual problem

Comment: try `"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -version` on the command line window.

Comment: That did strike my mind and when I paste it directly on command line, it works. I can't figure out why it fails in for statement.

Comment: you should check for a c&p error, the name of the bach and for the Batch file encoding type.

Comment: name of the batch/c&p isn't the issue. been trying to figure this out for a while now. how to change batch file encoding?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the %JAVA_HOME% Variable into:

```
C:\"Program Files"\jdk1.7.0_25
```

if you want it automated, type

```
set %JAVA_HOME%=C:\"Program Files"\jdk1.7.0_25
```

*REASON WHY:*
**The batch file does not accept the quotes; It is identifying them as a single file. So it attempts to find "C:\Program Files\jdk1.7.0_25" NOT as a folder path, but as a folder NAME in your root folder. If you type in
C:\"Program Files"\jdk1.7.0.25 it identifies that "Program Files" is a single file. If there are no redirection operators, It would think that the path would be like this;
C:\Program\Files\jdk1.7.0_25. It worked for me; It should probably work for you.**

*Hope that helped*

-SonorousTwo

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the explanation and the workaround!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, take a look at my QA: [How to get Java version in a batch script subroutine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50651070/how-to-get-java-version-in-a-batch-script-subroutine/50651302#50651302)

From my answer:

> It seems that piping the output to findstr was stripping the quotes for some reason.

I managed to fix the problem without Epic_Tonic's workaround (which would be very difficult to do with a path as a parameter).

---

This should work in your case:

```
set first=1
for /f "tokens=3" %%g in ('"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -version 2^>^&1') do (
    if !first!==1 echo %%~g
    set first=0
)
```

Note: `first` is for only searching the first line of `java -version`'s output ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1516428/4036475)).