# How to get Java version in a batch script subroutine?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, path, string-parsing

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675459/how-to-get-java-version-from-batch-script):

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%g in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "version"') do (
    @echo Output: %%g
    set JAVAVER=%%g
)
```

How can I put this into a subroutine and call it, passing a path to the java executable? Here's an example of my problem:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

call :GET_JAVA_VER "java"
goto END

:GET_JAVA_VER
    for /f "tokens=3" %%g in ('%1 -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "version"') do @echo %%g
    %1 -version 2>&1 | findstr /i "version"
goto :EOF

:END
    endlocal
```

This outputs:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
```

It seems to me that the for loop is evaluating the parameter (`%1`) differently.

**What's the difference?**

---

**EDIT**

Possible duplicate of [Java Version in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18152829/java-version-in-a-batch-file)

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18162222/4036475), if that is indeed the problem, I would have to somehow transform the passed in path by adding quotes around each directory containing spaces. That sounds like a pain and I'm hoping there's another explanation; I still don't get why in this case just passing in "java" doesn't work.

(Note: using `usebackq` and back-quotes makes no difference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that piping the output to `findstr` was stripping the quotes for some reason. I deduce this because when I removed the `^| findstr /i "version"` portion, this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

call :GET_JAVA_VER "java"
goto END

:GET_JAVA_VER
    for /f "tokens=3" %%g in ('%1 -version 2^>^&1') do @echo %%g
goto :EOF

:END
    endlocal
```

Outputs this:

```
"10.0.1"
Runtime
64-Bit
```

---

This modified script works (with full paths as well):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

call:GET_JAVA_VER "java"
goto END

:GET_JAVA_VER
    for /f "tokens=3" %%g in ('%~1 -version 2^>^&1') do (
        echo %%~g
        rem Stop after first line
        goto :EOF
    )
goto :EOF

:END
    endlocal
```