# how concatenate two variables in batch script?

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I want to do something like this in batch script. Please let me know if this is the proper or possible way to do it or any other way?

```
set var1=A

set var2=B

set AB=hi

set newvar=%var1%%var2%

echo %newvar%
```

This should produce the value "hi".

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Enabling delayed variable expansion solves you problem, the script produces "hi":

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set var1=A
set var2=B

set AB=hi

set newvar=!%var1%%var2%!

echo %newvar%
```

Comment: Thank you!!! it worked!! For disabling just to do is "setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion"?

Comment: No, you need to call endlocal. But beware that all variables in setlocal-endlocal block are local and not available from outside. You can save needed variables as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262287/make-an-environment-variable-survive-endlocal

Comment: You may review a more detailed description of this matter in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882395/why-is-delayed-expansion-in-a-batch-file-not-working-in-this-case)

Answer (score 11):

You can do it without `setlocal`, because of the `setlocal` command the variable won't  survive an `endlocal` because it was created in `setlocal`. In this way the variable will be defined the right way.

To do that use this code:

```
set var1=A

set var2=B

set AB=hi

call set newvar=%%%var1%%var2%%%

echo %newvar%
```

Note: You **MUST** use `call` before you set the variable or it won't work.

Comment: This is much more interesting than the vanilla `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`. It also works with global variables.

Comment: can you explain why we need to call `call` before `set` in the fourth line but not in the first three?

Answer (score 5):

The way is correct, but can be improved a bit with the extended set-syntax.

```
set "var=xyz"
```

Sets the var to the content until the last quotation mark, this ensures that no "hidden" spaces are appended.

Your code would look like

```
set "var1=A"
set "var2=B"
set "AB=hi"
set "newvar=%var1%%var2%"
echo %newvar% is the concat of var1 and var2
echo !%newvar%! is the indirect content of newvar
```

Comment: It doesn't echo the value "hi" instead it echos AB

Comment: You are right, I didn't read the last sentence, I only see the question about concatenating