# Renaming *.nfo files to match their *.mkv's

Tags: batch-file

Trying to organize a shows *.nfo files so they have the same name as the mkv(Edit:avi woops doesn't really change code) they match.

```
Test Folder:
76107.2.1.nfo 
76107.2.2.nfo
76107.2.3.nfo
Doctor Who - S02E01 (009) - Planet of Giants (1) - Planet of Giants.avi
Doctor Who - S02E01 (009) - Planet of Giants (2) - Dangerous Journey.avi
Doctor Who - S02E01 (009) - Planet of Giants (3) - Crisis.avi
```

Now the episode numbers in the 76107.2.*.nfo's are wrong in later folders the similarity in the test folder is only because it is the first of the season. so I can't simply compare names to match them up but they are in the right order so I'm trying to use counters to rename the first *.nfo the same as the first *.avi and then the second *.nfo the same as the second *.avi and so on!

I made a script I thought should work but it's doing nothing. Any help would be much appreciated! *Edit* It now works thanks to Aacini except for an odd bug noted under code.

```
@echo on
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set cnta=0
Set cntb=0
for %%b in (*.avi) do (
 set /a cnta=cnta+1
 set line_!cnta!=%%~Nb
)

for %%c in (*.nfo) do (
 set /a cntb=cntb+1
 for %%i in (!cntb!) do ren "%%~fc" "!line_%%i!.nfo"
)
```

Bug: The First nfo seems to get bumped to the end of the list but its place still kept. As in every other nfo is named to match its appropriate avi.

```
Test 1 (Original Test Folder) Results:
.nfo
Doctor Who - S02E01 (009) - Planet of Giants (1) - Planet of Giants.avi
Doctor Who - S02E01 (009) - Planet of Giants (2) - Dangerous Journey.avi
Doctor Who - S02E01 (009) - Planet of Giants (2) - Dangerous Journey.nfo
Doctor Who - S02E01 (009) - Planet of Giants (3) - Crisis.avi
Doctor Who - S02E01 (009) - Planet of Giants (3) - Crisis.nfo

Test 2 (Added Extra Bonus File) Results:
Doctor Who - S02E01 (009) - Planet of Giants (1) - Planet of Giants.avi
Doctor Who - S02E01 (009) - Planet of Giants (2) - Dangerous Journey.avi
Doctor Who - S02E01 (009) - Planet of Giants (2) - Dangerous Journey.nfo
Doctor Who - S02E01 (009) - Planet of Giants (3) - Crisis.avi
Doctor Who - S02E01 (009) - Planet of Giants (3) - Crisis.nfo
Doctor Who - S02E01 (009) - Planet of Giants (4) - The Making of Planet of Giants.avi
Doctor Who - S02E01 (009) - Planet of Giants (4) - The Making of Planet of Giants.nfo
```

Some folders will contain bonus videos at the end of the list that do not have matching nfo's but they are always at the end. I read the nfo's to verify only the ".nfo"(Test 1)/"Doctor Who - S02E01 (009) - Planet of Giants (4) - The Making of Planet of Giants.nfo"(Test 2) were misplaced they should of been "Doctor Who - S02E01 (009) - Planet of Giants (1) - Planet of Giants.nfo"

Comment: You might have better luck by sorting your file list with `dir` options. But I don't know if you're going to have an environment space problems with a long list of variables.

Comment: You also need a double expansion of variables in that second loop. Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199931/how-expand-a-cmd-shell-variable-twice-recursively

Comment: This is probably a better reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882395/why-is-delayed-expansion-in-a-batch-file-not-working-in-this-case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right term to name your `line_!cnta!` variables is *array*. You may review a complete description of array management in Batch files at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990). For example, your code may be fixed this way:

**EDIT**: *Small bug fixed*

```
@echo on
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set cnta=0
Set cntb=0

for %%b in (*.mkv) do (
 set /a cnta=cnta+1
 set line_!cnta!=%%~Nb
)

for /F "delims=" %%c in ('dir /B *.nfo') do (
 set /a cntb=cntb+1
 for %%i in (!cntb!) do ren "%%~fc" "!line_%%i!.nfo"
)
```

Comment: I'd argue that a better name would be "array-like," since it's not a true array. It's the same as the difference between a folder containing a bunch of files and an archive file containing those same files that doesn't use any compression.

Comment: @Dracrius: Excuse me, but the rename logic is the same you posted in your question; I just fixed the point on the access to the array elements. If you want that we also fix the rename logic, then you must post a list of files that cause the error and the desired result. Please, edit your _question_ and place the list of names inside a code tag, do NOT post list of names here, in comments...

Comment: @SomethingDark: I disagree. An array is a _data structure_: a variable comprised of a series of elements that are accessed via a numeric index or subscript. If certain data uses this structure, it is an array; if not, then is not. You don't need a given programming language or a specific notation (even nor a computer!) to manage an array...

Comment: True, but batch arrays are just a group of variables that happen to have similar names and are otherwise unrelated.

Comment: @SomethingDark: You are talking about the _implementation details_ of arrays in a Batch file! These details make this data structure to not be an "array"? In such a case, there are NOT arrays in assembly language! (nor in the computer memory for that matter)...

Comment: @Aacini: Thank you for your help I have updated my question! I'm totally stumped on whats wrong with rename logic.

Comment: @Dracius: I found the bug! It is related to the process of several files when they are renamed: the first file renamed is processed twice by `FOR` command. I fixed the bug. Please, copy again the program above and test it...

Comment: @Aacini: Perfect thank you very much I never would of found that on my own.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is going to work for you. You should change the `echo ren` to `ren` once you decide it looks right.

```
@echo on
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set cnta=0
set cntb=0

for %%a in (*.mkv) do (
    set /a cnta=cnta+1
    set line_!cnta!=%%a
)

for %%b in (*.nfo) do (
    set /a cntb=cntb+1
    set newname=line_!cntb!
    call set newname=%%!newname!%%
    echo ren "%%~fb" "!newname!"
)
```

I think you'll prefer a loop like this. I actually tested it all out this time:

```
@echo on
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set cnta=0
set cntb=0

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`dir *.mkv /a-d /b /on`) do (
    set /a cnta=cnta+1
    set line_!cnta!=%%a
)

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%b in (`dir *.nfo /a-d /b /on`) do (
    set /a cntb=cntb+1
    set newname=line_!cntb!
    call set newname=%%!newname!%%
    echo ren "%%~fb" "!newname!"
)
```

If you have any real interest in playing with batch scripts, you're going to need a lot of patience and trial and error before it really starts to click. It can be very intricate and complicated.

Comment: This still doesn't do anything. Thanks for trying it looks better then mine but it won't even echo!

Comment: You were using `for /f` when you really want `for` although I think you'll still want the option using a `dir` command. I edited the answer.

Comment: Why will the dir version be better? And I'm sorry to say it still does nothing.

Comment: @Dracrius dir is better because of /on - that orders by name to insure that you get the files in the correct order. Both examples here work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Since you appear to be looking for an alternative, does each .nfo file contain the name of its corresponding .mkv file?  If so, you could use `find` and conditional execution to pair the .mkv with its .nfo by the .nfo's contents.  This is much (**much!**) less efficient than shawn and Aacini's answers, but at least you don't have to worry about whether or not the files are in order this way.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

for %%I in (*.mkv) do (
    for %%x in (76107*.nfo) do if not exist "%%~nI.nfo" (
        find /i "%%~nxI" "%%x" >NUL && ren "%%x" "%%~nI.nfo"
    )
)
```