# how to concatenate two variables when one has spaces in it in AzureDevops batch file

Tags: batch-file, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I have this input in my ps script. I am passing `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` system variable to get the path in the input `%1`. The path has spaces i.e. `E:\Build Agents\Agent2\_work\15\a`. I need to concatenate this with other path but I am not able to do so.

```
set BuildDrop=%1
set Directory=%BuildDrop% + "\adapters\bin"
```

This is my output, which is incorrect as `Directory` should be something like `E:\Build Agents\Agent2\_work\15\a\adapters\bin`. How to solve this?

```
set BuildDrop="E:\Build Agents\Agent2\_work\15\a" 

set Directory="E:\Build Agents\Agent2\_work\15\a" + "\adapters\bin"
```

My task is like this in my build pipeline

```
Task         : Batch script
Description  : Run a Windows command or batch script and optionally allow it to change the environment
Version      : 1.1.10
```

Comment: wut is diz? bash? perl? cmd?

Comment: @AdminOfThings yes it powershell and azureDevops

Comment: @4c74356b41this is bash. I have updated the details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this :

```
set BuildDrop=%1
set Directory= %BuildDrop%\adapters\bin
echo %Directory%
```

**Sample Output**

[image]

This is the concatenation code.

```
%BuildDrop%\adapters\bin
```

In my above sample I am trying to concatenate **C:\Users\svijay\Desktop** & **\adapters\bin** using the batch script

And the output : C:\Users\svijay\Desktop\adapters\bin

**UPDATE :**

```
@echo off 
set BuildDrop=%1
set Directory= %BuildDrop%\adapters\bin
set Directory= %Directory:"=%
echo %Directory%
```

If you have space, you could provide the "" to provide input.
In your code you could remove the double quotes.

**%Directory:"=%**  - Removes the Double quotes from the string literal.

**Sample output :**

[image]

Comment: @mehul - the above is for the batch. Pls let me know if this is the one you are looking for ?

Comment: yes but the problem is `BuildDrop="E:\Build Agents\Agent2\_work\15\a"` has apostrophe who also get concatenated. That I don't want. I need an apostrophe to read a value that has spaces.

Comment: BuildDrop=E:\Build Agents\Agent2\_work\15\a

...Don't give the apostrophe . Type the string without the apostrpohe. Something like above example

Comment: If you closely look in my sample output. I have not given the apostrophe. The output is just  C:\Users\svijay\Desktop\adapters\bin

Comment: yes because your input doesn't have space. Try with `word.bat C:\Users\s vijay\Desktop`. My input folder has space, therefore, need an apostrophe.

Comment: Got your point. I have updated my answer.  Pls check and let me know :)

Comment: Yes, it solved the problem. I have added my solution also. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for this. Since my `%1` had space I needed to remove apostrohphe before assigning. I did it using `~` variable. working code looks like this.

```
set "BuildDrop=%~1"
set "Directory=%BuildDrop%\adapters\bin"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use powershell task in the Azure DevOps to concatenate two variables.
Sample:

```
Write-Host "Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory is $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"
Write-Host "Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory is $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\adapters\bin"
```

Result:
[image]

In addition, I found a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113413/how-do-i-concatenate-strings-and-variables-in-powershell), please also check it.

**Update1**

Use power shell script in the Azure DevOps pipeline

```
$testpath1 = "E:\Build Agents\Agent2\_work\15\a"
$testpath2 = "\adapters\bin"
Write-Host "path is $($testpath1)$($testpath2)"
```

Result:

[image]

Use local power shell

Result:

[image]

**Update2**

.bat file

```
set testpath1=E:\Build Agents\Agent2\_work\15\a
set testpath2=\adapters\bin
set newpath=%testpath1%%testpath2%
echo %newpath%
```

Pipeline result:

[image]

Comment: how to set the variable value? Write-host will only print it.

Comment: If you want to use Azure DevOps variable you should use logging commands `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue"` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell

Comment: Hi @MehulParmar, I have updated the answer, please check it,.

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT yes this will print it. But how to set the value of a variable. i want to change the value of the variable `Directory`

Comment: @MehulParmar, do you mean that you want to change the env variable Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory? Or add a new env variable in the pipeline? If yes, please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63261717/13903626)

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT I want to set the value in my bat file only.

Comment: @MehulParmar, please check the update2, set the value in the bat file and concatenate two variables, then print it.

Comment: Please also check this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846560/how-concatenate-two-variables-in-batch-script)

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT yes sure I will have a look. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use this to create Azure DevOps variable containing your path

```
powershell: |
  
  $directory = $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  $newDirectory = $directory + "\adapters\bin"
                                        
  Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar]$newDirectory "
```

and if you need set variable in powershell script

```bsh
$BuildDrop=$args[0]
$Directory=$BuildDrop + "\adapters\bin"
```

[Here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/powershell/how-to-use-parameters-in-powershell/) you have an article how to use parameters in powershell.