# Temporarily interrupt SETLOCAL

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp, cmd

I have a script that has a lot of use of the `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` command, so I start the script off that way (less headaches). However, it does not allow you to use the `!` character without escaping each instance of it (and I want to create a long line of `!`s for an error logging section  =D ) and I don't want to escape every one of them.

Is there a way to temporarily break out of `SETLOCAL`, then reenter it keeping all previously created variables within the original `SETLOCAL`?

For example:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set var=HELLO
ECHO %var%
ENDLOCAL

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
ECHO %var%
```

The 2nd `ECHO` will not give you the previous value of `var`

EDIT: `^` will not allow you to escape the `!` inside `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`

Comment: What's with 'setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion ... Endlocal' ?

Comment: @jeb but enabling setlocal enabledelayedexpansion after an endlocal will not keep all variables created within the previous setlocal command.

Answer (score 1):

```
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set var=Value! with! many! Bangs!
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo !var!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can nest it like Aacini shows it.
Or you can use the return technic or escape `!` inside a EnableDelayed block with `^^!`

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo 1^^!^^!^^!^^!^^!^^!^^!
REM *** Or use a self removing quote
echo !="! 2^!^!^!^!^!^!

Setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
echo 3 !!!!!!!!
set var=Hello
(
  endlocal
  rem Bring the value behind the endlocal barrier
  set var=%var%
)

echo var is still there, %var%
```

The return technic can also be used for exclamation marks, but then it is a bit more complex.
It can be found at [Make an environment variable survive ENDLOCAL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8257951/463115)