# Qt Creator: How to run a windows batch file and get result

Tags: c++, windows, qt, batch-file

I currently have this batch file:

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set Times=0

for /f "skip=1" %%p in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage') do (

set Cpusage!Times!=%%p

set /A Times=!Times! + 1

)

echo %Cpusage0%
```

And I would like to run it in a standard C++ Qt windows application and store the percentage in a variable. I can see you can run batch files using `QProcess`, but I'm not sure how to get the result.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Not sure why you need the batch file if you can get the CPU usage *directly* in C++ with [native code](http://www.tidytutorials.com/2009/09/windows-c-get-cpu-and-memory.html).

Comment: The idea of @wOxxOm is definitly a better approach then using a batch. However, if you need a batch for some reason: `QProcess` inherits `QIODevice`, meaning you can use it just like a file and read or write data from/to the process.

Comment: Is this a question about programming in Qt or about setting up Qt Creator?

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple solutions to this task (standard C++, Qt, WinAPI, etc.), I will list a few of those. I have tested and verified all the listed ones (in case I did not make a mistake, they should work fine).

However all the solutions listed below requires you to change one line in the batch script you provided. 
The reason for that is the last line "`echo %Cpusage0%`" only *prints* the result value to the command prompt instead of *returning* it.

For that reason I **changed the last line of the batch file**

**from** `echo %Cpusage0%`

**to** `exit %Cpusage0%`

This returns the value in the variable `Cpusage0` from the command prompt.

**Solutions:**

In general: the batch file needs to be run through the command interpreter ([cmd.exe](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) - command prompt on Windows). In addition you need to specify the **/C option** to the cmd.exe if you wish to run only one command in the interpreter and then terminate it (that's true in your case).

So the command you wish to execute is:

```
std::string BatchFile = "..."; // Access path to the batch file.
std::string Command = "cmd.exe /C " + BatchFile;
```

*Note:* if you change the `Command` std::string the previously obtained c_str() pointers become invalid.
So either

- don't change the std::string while the std::system() call is running,
- use a local variable for storing the command (like i did in the examples),
- copy the command into a C-string (`[const] char*`) pointer or
  preferably into a smart pointer character array
  ([`std::unique_ptr<char[]>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)).

In case of using C-string, don't forget to delete it.

**Summary:**

1. Standard C++ - [std::system(...)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system)

   A, Waiting for [std::system(...)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) to finish. This **blocks** the calling thread.

   B, Running [std::system(...)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) in a different thread with [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread). This **does not block** the calling thread.

   C, Running [std::system(...)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) in a different thread with [std::async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async). This **does not block** the calling thread.
2. Qt - [QProcess](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html)

   A, Waiting for [QProcess](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) to finish. This **blocks** the calling thread.

   B, Signaling a slot with [QProcess::finished()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#finished). This **does not block** the calling thread.
3. WinAPI - [CreateProcess(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx)

   A, Waiting for [CreateProcess(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) to finish. This **blocks** the calling thread.

   B, Starting a new thread ([CreateThread(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx)) to wait for [CreateProcess(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) to finish. This **does not block** the calling thread.

*Alternative*: I would like to mention the same thing ***@wOxxOm*** advised in a comment on the question - you can get the CPU usage directly in C++. This has been asked on StackOverflow a couple of times before, here are some examples:

[How to determine CPU and memory consumption from inside a process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process)

[Retrieving CPU Load Percent total in Windows with C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23143693/retrieving-cpu-load-percent-total-in-windows-with-c)

*Note*: I haven't verified the "cpu usage directly from C++" answers myself, but one is heavily upvoted and the other one is accepted as an answer.

---

### **In details:**

*Note*: These are minimalistic solutions with minimal error checking. In case of using a "multi-threaded solution" do not forget to add proper protection for the shared resources (for example using `std::atomic<int>` or std::mutex to protect the shared variable).

### 1. *Standard C++* - [std::system(...)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system)

You can execute the batch file in the current thread and wait for the result by calling [std::system(...)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) with the ***Command*** and storing the result in an int variable (the percentage value).

***A,*** Plain blocking [std::system(...)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) call.

***This blocks the calling thread.***

```
    auto runBatchSTDSystemWaited(const std::string& BatchFile) -> int {
        auto Command = std::string("cmd.exe /C " + BatchFile);

        return std::system(Command.c_str());
    }
```

You can do the same in another thread (and continue to do other things while waiting for the result) by using either [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) or [std::async(...)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async).

***B,*** [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread). ([std::promise](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise), [std::future](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future))

***This does not block the calling thread.***

```
    auto runBatchSTDSystemThread(const std::string& BatchFile, std::shared_ptr<std::promise<int>> Promise) -> std::future<int> {
    // Note: the Promise object must exist until the last call to either the promise or the future objects.

        auto Command = std::string("cmd.exe /C " + BatchFile);
        auto Future = Promise->get_future();

        std::thread Thread([](decltype(Command) STDSystemCommand, decltype(Promise) ResultPromise) -> void {
            ResultPromise->set_value_at_thread_exit(std::system(STDSystemCommand.c_str()));
        }, Command, Promise);
        Thread.detach();

        return Future;
        // Note: You can access the CPU usage value by calling the std::future::get() function of the returned future object.
    }
```

The following basically wraps the **1/B** solution into 1 call.

***C,*** [std::async(...)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async)

***This does not block the calling thread.***

```
    auto runBatchSTDSystemAsync(const std::string& BatchFile) -> std::future<int> {
        auto Command = std::string("cmd.exe /C " + BatchFile);

        // std::async can be forced to create new thread with std::launch::async launch policy.
        // Make sure that the Command string exists until the new thread ends (reason for string copy).
        // The lambda-function is required to copy the command string to the new thread.
        auto Future = std::future<int>(std::async(std::launch::async, [](decltype(Command) STDSystemCommand) -> int {
                                           return std::system(STDSystemCommand.c_str());
                                       }, Command));

        return Future;
        // Note: You can access the CPU usage value by calling the std::future::get() function of the returned future object.
    }
```

### 2. *Qt* - [QProcess](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html)

Similarly to the standard c++ solutions you can wait for the [QProcess](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) thread to finish the execution and obtain the result.

***A,*** [QProcess::waitForFinished(-1)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#waitForFinished)

**This blocks the calling thread.**

```
auto runBatchQtQProcessWaited(const std::string& BatchFile) -> int {
    QProcess Process;
    auto Command = QString("cmd.exe");
    auto Arguments = QStringList{
            QString("/C"),
            QString::fromStdString(BatchFile)
    };

    Process.start(Command, Arguments);
    Process.waitForFinished(-1);

    return Process.exitCode();
}
```

With Qt another possibility is to signal an appropriate slot function for receiving the result of the [QProcess](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html).

***B,*** [QProcess::finished()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#finished)

**This does not block the calling thread.**

```
class SlotClass : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    SlotClass(std::shared_ptr<QProcess> Process);

    auto getResult() const -> int;

public slots:
    /*auto*/ void onPostFinishQtQProcess(int ExitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus ExitStatus) /*-> void*/; 
    // Seems like Qt 5.5 moc compiler fails to correctly recognize auto declared slots. (Throws error when compiling at ":".)

private:
    std::shared_ptr<QProcess> Process;
    int Result;
};

SlotClass::SlotClass(std::shared_ptr<QProcess> Process) :
    Process(Process),
    Result(-1) {}


auto SlotClass::getResult() const -> int {
    return this->Result;
}

/*auto*/ void SlotClass::onPostFinishQtQProcess(int ExitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus ExitStatus) /*-> void*/ {
    if (ExitStatus == QProcess::CrashExit)
        throw std::runtime_error("Batch process crashed.");

    this->Result = ExitCode;
}

auto runBatchQtQProcessSignaled(const std::string& BatchFile, const SlotClass& SlotObject) -> void {
    auto Command = QString("cmd.exe");
    auto Arguments = QStringList{
            QString("/C"),
            QString::fromStdString(BatchFile)
    };

    QObject::connect(SlotObject.getProcess().get(), SIGNAL(finished(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)),
                     &SlotObject, SLOT(onPostFinishQtQProcess(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)));

    SlotObject.getProcess()->start(Command, Arguments);
}
```

### 3. *WinAPI* - [CreateProcess(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx)

There is a variation for the blocking wait with WinAPI as well.

***A,*** [CreateProcess(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx)

***This blocks the calling thread.***

```
auto runBatchWinAPICreateProcessWaited(const std::string& BatchFile) -> int {
    auto Command = "cmd.exe /C " + BatchFile;

    // Creates wide string array from the narrow command string.
    auto WideStringConverter = std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>>();
    auto WideCommand = WideStringConverter.from_bytes(Command);
    auto WideCommandArray = std::make_unique<wchar_t[]>(WideCommand.length() + 1);
    std::wcscpy(WideCommandArray.get(), WideCommand.c_str());

    // Initializes necessary structures.
    STARTUPINFO BatchStartupInformation;
    std::memset(&BatchStartupInformation, 0, sizeof(BatchStartupInformation));
    BatchStartupInformation.cb = sizeof(BatchStartupInformation);

    PROCESS_INFORMATION BatchProcessInformation;
    std::memset(&BatchProcessInformation, 0, sizeof(BatchProcessInformation));

    // Creates a new command prompt process with no window and executes the given batch file.
    if (!CreateProcess(nullptr, WideCommandArray.get(), nullptr, nullptr, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW,
                   nullptr, nullptr, &BatchStartupInformation, &BatchProcessInformation))
        throw std::exception(("Could not create process for running the batch file. Error code: " + std::to_string(GetLastError())).c_str());

    // Waits until the created process has already finished.
    auto WaitResult = WaitForSingleObject(BatchProcessInformation.hProcess, INFINITE);
    if (WAIT_FAILED == WaitResult)
        throw std::runtime_error(("Waiting for batch process failed. Error code: " + std::to_string(GetLastError())).c_str());
    //else if (WAIT_TIMEOUT == WaitResult)
    //    ;   //...

    auto ProcessResult = 0ul;
    if (!GetExitCodeProcess(BatchProcessInformation.hProcess, &ProcessResult))
        throw std::exception(("Could not retrieve process exit code after running batch file. Exit code: " + std::to_string(GetLastError())).c_str());

    CloseHandle(BatchProcessInformation.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(BatchProcessInformation.hThread);

    return ProcessResult;
}
```

Or you can do the same as **3/A**, but create a new thread to wait for the batch file to finish.

***B,*** [CreateThread()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx), [CreateProcess()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx)

***This does not block the calling thread.***

```
auto runBatchWinAPICreateProcessEvent(const std::string& BatchFile) -> void {
    auto Command = "cmd.exe /C " + BatchFile;

    // Creates wide string array from the narrow command string.
    auto WideStringConverter = std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>>();
    auto WideCommand = WideStringConverter.from_bytes(Command);
    auto WideCommandArray = std::make_unique<wchar_t[]>(WideCommand.length() + 1);
    std::wcscpy(WideCommandArray.get(), WideCommand.c_str());

    // Initializes necessary structures.
    STARTUPINFO BatchStartupInformation;
    std::memset(&BatchStartupInformation, 0, sizeof(BatchStartupInformation));
    BatchStartupInformation.cb = sizeof(BatchStartupInformation);

    PROCESS_INFORMATION BatchProcessInformation;
    std::memset(&BatchProcessInformation, 0, sizeof(BatchProcessInformation));

    // Creates a new command prompt process with no window and executes the given batch file.
    if (!CreateProcess(nullptr, WideCommandArray.get(), nullptr, nullptr, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW,
                   nullptr, nullptr, &BatchStartupInformation, &BatchProcessInformation))
        throw std::exception(("Could not create process for running the batch file. Error code: " + std::to_string(GetLastError())).c_str());

    if (!CreateThread(nullptr, 0, &waitForWinAPICreateProcessResult, new PROCESS_INFORMATION(BatchProcessInformation), 0, nullptr))
        throw std::exception(("Could not create process for retrieving the result of the batch file. Error code: " + std::to_string(GetLastError())).c_str());
}

auto WINAPI waitForWinAPICreateProcessResult(LPVOID ThreadParameter) -> DWORD {
    auto BatchProcessInformation = std::unique_ptr<PROCESS_INFORMATION>(reinterpret_cast<PROCESS_INFORMATION*>(ThreadParameter));

    // Waits until the created process has already finished.
    auto WaitResult = WaitForSingleObject(BatchProcessInformation->hProcess, INFINITE);
    if (WAIT_FAILED == WaitResult)
        throw std::runtime_error(("Waiting for batch process failed. Error code: " + std::to_string(GetLastError())).c_str());
    //else if (WAIT_TIMEOUT == WaitResult)
    //    ;   //...

    auto ProcessResult = 0ul;
    if (!GetExitCodeProcess(BatchProcessInformation->hProcess, &ProcessResult))
        throw std::exception(("Could not retrieve process exit code after running batch file. Exit code: " + std::to_string(GetLastError())).c_str());

    // You have the result in the ProcessResult variable.

    CloseHandle(BatchProcessInformation->hProcess);
    CloseHandle(BatchProcessInformation->hThread);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: seems like these return an int from the batch file.  how to return the output from the batch file?

Comment: Batch scripts can only return integer [exit codes](https://ss64.com/nt/exit.html) that is the mechanism I was using in my answer.
But there are some workarounds to returning arbitrary result from a batch script, like writing to stdout or a file or [using environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11486159/3981670).