# Endlocal rtnLocal macro and ! in filepaths

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to utilize the different %rtnLocal% and %endlocal% return macros in order to utilize in my batch to carry-over 1000's of filepaths & names that contain "!" as posted in [preserving exclamation marks in variable between setlocals batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869394/preserving-exclamation-marks-in-variable-between-setlocals-batch).

I choose macros as I've also seen dbendham, jeb, Aacini, and others discuss how macros are generally a faster option; as opposed to Call functions or Call files.

Here is my sample and I just can't get them to function properly, I am not sure what I am doing wrong if perhaps a win10 since then has slightly modified that causes this to stop working.
Setlocal(2) is the contains 1 of the 'return macros', after which are simulated setlocal levels for testing, and no matter what I change the level to rtnLocal*2 , *4, etc.. (except for more than setlocals are set; it then sets outside the batch at the prompt level) it does not populate outside the existing setlocal.

Thank you for any clarification

Edit: Corrected Setlocal imbalanace.

```
@echo OFF
Setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
SETlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
        ::Return V2.0 - 2016 -jeb
    :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869394/preserving-exclamation-marks-in-variable-between-setlocals-batch/29869518#29869518
    @rem The other/only problem is when you try to transfer a variable over an endlocal barrier (like endlocal & set "RetVar2=%modTestVar%").
    @rem This is not trivial.
    @rem 
    @rem This is a batch macro for this, used like this %endlocal% modTestVar
if "!" equ "" (
  >&2 echo *** 'retLocals' macro must be loaded under 'disableDelayedExpansion'
  exit /b 1
)

set LF=^


set ^"\n=^^^%LF%%LF%^%LF%%LF%^^"
@rem single carriage-return char 0x0D (usable as !CR! under edx, only)
for /F "usebackq delims= " %%C in (`copy /z "%~f0" nul`) do set "CR=%%C"

:: macro to return multiple LF-free variables across endlocal barriers
::
:: syntax:  %retLocals%[*cnt] out1[=in1] [, out2[=in2] [, out3[=in3]] ...]
:: - 'out#' (#=1,2,3,...) are variables being returned/set in the outer context
:: - 'in#' are local/inner context variables whose values are returned
:: - optional [=in#] defaults to 'out#=out#'
:: - optional [*cnt] is the nesting depth, default '*1' for one 'endlocal' call
:: - spaces around ',' commas and '=' equal signs are optional
::
:: e.g. %retLocals% var               copies inner 'var' across 1 endlocal
::                                    to namesake 'var' in the outer context
::
::      %retLocals%*2 out1=in1, out2  copies 'in1', 'out2' across 2 endlocal's
::                                    to 'out1', 'out2' in the outer context
::
::      %retLocals%*0 out=in          copies 'in' to 'out' within same context
::                                    like 'set out=%in%' but safe against
::                                    embedded quotes and funny chars except LF
::
:: ! names of variables 'out#', 'in#' are expected to be plain quote-less
::   well behaved strings, with no funny (<|>^%!=,;) characters
:: ! 'in#' names must not be 'cd' since that's used by %retLocals% internally
:: ! outer environment other than 'out#' is not modified
::   except for '%retLocals%*0' with '*0' de-nesting, which clears 'cd'
:: ! errorlevel is reset to '0' but the caller can preserve the inner value
::   if needed via '(%retLocals% ...) & set outErr=%errorlevel%'

set ^"retLocals=for %%# in (1 2) do if %%#==2 (%\n%
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion%\n%
  set x=%\n%
  for %%L in ("!LF!") do for %%R in ("!CR!") do ^
  for /f "tokens=1,*" %%U in ("!cd!") do ^
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=*" %%U in ("%%U*%%U") do (%\n%
    set v=%%~V%\n%
    for /f "delims=" %%V in ("!v:,=%%~L!") do ^
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims== " %%V in ("%%~V=%%~V") do (%\n%
      set w=!%%~W!%\n%
      if defined w (%\n%
        set w=!w:^"=""q!%\n%
        set w=!w:%%~R=""r!%\n%
        set "path=" ^& set "pathExt=;"%\n%
        set "w=!w:^=^^^^!"%\n%
        call set "w=%%w:^!=^^^!%%"%\n%
        set "w=!w:^^=^!")%\n%
      if defined x set x=!x!!LF!%\n%
      set x=!x!"%%~V=!%%~W!"!LF!"%%~V=!w!")%\n%
    for /f "delims=" %%X in ("!x!") do (%\n%
      if "!cd:~0,1!"=="*" (%\n%
        for /l %%U in (0 1 %%U) do endlocal%\n%
        set "cd=" ^& call;)%\n%
      if errorlevel 1 ((if "!"=="" (%\n%
        set "%%~X"!%\n%
        for /f "delims==" %%V in ("%%~X") do (%\n%
          if defined %%~V (%\n%
            set %%~V=!%%~V:""r=%%~R!%\n%
            set %%~V=!%%~V:^""q="!%\n%
        )))) ^& call;%\n%
      ) else (if not "!"=="" set "%%~X") ^& call%\n%
))) else set cd=*1^"
SETlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
SETlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
    SETlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
        SETlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
            SETlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
            ECHO -----------------------------
            SET /a "ID2=2"
            %retLocals%*3 ID5=ID2
            Echo This0: %ID2%,%ID5%
            EndLocal
        Echo This1: %ID2%,%ID5%
        EndLocal
    Echo This2: %ID2%,%ID5%
    EndLocal
Echo This3: %ID2%,%ID5%
ECHO *******************************
EndLocal
Echo This4: %ID2%,%ID5%
EndLocal
Echo This5: %ID2%,%ID5%
EndLocal
EndLocal
```

Comment: I'm not sure that you should necessarily expect to get a speed increase by using macros. _BTW, your posted code has a `setlocal`/`endlocal` imbalance, (six to eight respectively).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your expectation is wrong.

The macro exits 4 levels of endlocals, that works, you can see that `id5` is set.
But you can't expect, that the variable still exists after you execute another endlocal.
Or you have to use the macro again to `endlocal` with variable preservation.

Btw. To debug setlocal/endlocal behaviour you could add some debug code:

```
@echo OFF
set level=0
set "DEBUG_SETLOCAL= & set /a level+=1 & <nul set /p ".=setlocal: " & set "level""
set "DEBUG_ENDLOCAL= & <nul set /p ".=endlocal: " & set "level""
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion %DEBUG_SETLOCAL%
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion %DEBUG_SETLOCAL%
...
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion %DEBUG_SETLOCAL%
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion %DEBUG_SETLOCAL%
    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion %DEBUG_SETLOCAL%
        setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion %DEBUG_SETLOCAL%
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion %DEBUG_SETLOCAL%
            ECHO -----------------------------
            SET /a "ID2=2"
            <nul set /p ".=current: " & set "level"
            %retLocals%*3 ID5=ID2
            Echo This0: id2=%ID2% id5=%ID5%
            EndLocal %DEBUG_ENDLOCAL%
        Echo This1: %ID2%,%ID5%
        EndLocal %DEBUG_ENDLOCAL%
    Echo This2: %ID2%,%ID5%
...
```

The output is then

```
setlocal: level=1
setlocal: level=2
setlocal: level=3
setlocal: level=4
setlocal: level=5
setlocal: level=6
setlocal: level=7
-----------------------------
current: level=7
This0: id2= id5=2
endlocal: level=3
This1: ,
endlocal: level=2
This2: ,
...
```

After `current: level=7` you use your macro and it executes 4 times `endlocal` internally.
`This0: id2= id5=2` shows the expected output.

Btw.

- You should avoid the useless `EnableExtension` everywhere.
- Don't use reserved variable names like `cd`
- debug your macro with `set` statements, like `set "## here i am ##" %\n%` or `set "myvar" %\n%` to show the variable content