# Batch - How to pass a multiline string value between variables

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, environment-variables

The problem is `echo !out!` show all lines but `echo %data%` which assigned from `!out!` only show first line

```
@echo off

call :f
echo %data%

:f
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set out=
set NL=^


for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b') do (
    if defined out set "out=!out!!NL!"
    set "out=!out!%%i"
)
echo !out!
set data=!out!
exit /b 0
```

What is the correct way to pass the value entirely to other variable which i need to use freely after `endlocal`?

---

Thank you @**aschipfl**'s for your answer that clarify that it's impossible to do it without end up in `for-in` loop again. Actually all that I want is to simplify my code without have to write `for-in` loop many times by turn it into a subroutine. I've solved it by passing the subroutine to the subroutine instead.

Comment: this can be completely avoided by disabling delayed expansion, though the escaping is complicated&content of `out` will not be handled properly. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8257951/12861751 ...

Comment: I have no real idea why you've created this question, but not specifically told the readers that you're trying to create a variable, to hold the entire content of your `Dir` command's output. My question is What is the reason for using `EndLocal` where you have? _(all it is effectively doing is undefining the variables named `NL` and `out`, and you could have simply used `Set "NL="` and `Set "out="`, or `For %%G In (NL out) Do Set "%%G="` immediately after the `For` loop to do that)_!

Comment: @Compo Sorry. I thought it is clearer by simplify the question. I've edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As derived from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133), you cannot echo a multi-line string using immediate (`%`-)expansion, because everything after the first line-break is ignored.

To make your script working you need to correct two issues:

- before the line `endlocal & set data=%out%` you must replace every new-line in variable `out` by an escaped new-line, that is the sequence `^` plus new-line plus new-line, which is exactly the same that you are using for defining the variable `NL`;
- `echo %data%` truncates the displayed string at the first occurrence of a new-line in the value of variable `data`, so you need to use `set data` to show the actual content of the variable (or more precisely said, of all variables whose names begin with `data`);

Both of these items are commented (`rem`) in the following code:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set out=
set NL=^


for /F "delims= eol=|" %%i in ('dir /b') do (
    if defined out set "out=!out!!NL!"
    set "out=!out!%%i"
)
echo * Original variable content:
set out
rem // Replace every new-line by an escaped new-line:
set out=!out:^%NL%%NL%=^^^%NL%%NL%^%NL%%NL%!
echo * Modified variable content:
set out
endlocal & set data=%out%

rem // Do not use `echo` to show true content of variable:
echo * Returned variable content:
set data
echo * Mistaken variable content:
echo %data%

exit /B 0
```

Although the variable value is now correctly passed over the `endlocal` barrier, this approach is not exactly brilliant, because it does not allow you to use variable `%data%` (again because everything after the first line-break is ignored as initially mentioned), unless you have got delayed expansion enabled in the hosting `cmd` instance, which would permit to use `!data!`.

---

Another remaining problem is that special characters in the multi-line string (like `^`, `&`, `(`, `)` and `"`, `<`, `>`, `|`) may cause syntax errors or other unexpected issues. However, this can be avoided by using a `for` meta-variable rather than a normal environment variable for passing the variable value beyond the `endlocal` barrier, because the former are expanded after special character recognition, in contrast to the latter, which are expanded before:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set out=
set NL=^


for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b') do (
    if defined out set "out=!out!!NL!"
    set "out=!out!%%i"
)
echo # Original variable content:
set out
rem /* Use a `for` meta-variable rather than a normal environment variable to
rem    pass the variable value beyond the `endlocal` barrier;
rem    a standard `for` loop can be used here, because there are not going to be
rem    wildcards `?` and `*` in the variable value since they have already been
rem    resolved by `dir`; `for /F` cannot be used here due to the new-lines: */
for %%j in ("!out!") do endlocal & set "data=%%~j"

rem // Do not use `echo` to show true content of variable:
echo # Returned variable content:
set data
echo # Mistaken variable content:
echo %data%

exit /B 0
```

The problem not being able to use variable `%data%` remains though.

---

To be able to use variable `%data%` with immediate expansion you could however simply store escaped new-lines rather than literal ones in the variable, because upon expansion you will have the intended literal new-line:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set out=
set NL=^


for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b') do (
    if defined out set "out=!out!!NL!"
    set "out=!out!%%i"
)
echo # Original variable content:
set out
rem // Replace every new-line by an escaped new-line:
set out=!out:^%NL%%NL%=^^^%NL%%NL%^%NL%%NL%!
echo # Modified variable content:
set out
rem /* Use a `for` meta-variable rather than a normal environment variable to
rem    pass the variable value beyond the `endlocal` barrier;
rem    a standard `for` loop can be used here, because there are not going to be
rem    wildcards `?` and `*` in the variable value since they have already been
rem    resolved by `dir`; `for /F` cannot be used here due to the new-lines: */
for %%j in ("!out!") do endlocal & set "data=%%~j"

rem // Do not use `echo` to show true content of variable:
echo # Actual variable content:
set data
echo # Parsed variable content:
echo %data%

exit /B 0
```

But regard that this is only going to work when `%data%` does not appear within quoted (`""`) strings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So basically I'll still need to use a `for-in` loop to copy the value entirely. That's clear