# Read text file lines starting with numbers using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, text-files

I'm not sure if this is possible, but is there a way for a batch file to read a text file, but skip lines that do not start with a number?

For example:

```
handled
219278
check
219276
control
219274
co
219268
```

Can a for loop skip handled, check, control, etc.?

I know this:

```
cscript C:\Users\c1921\Test\curltest.vbs"!$MyVar!">>C:\Users\c1921\Test\Datapoints\!$MyVar!.txt
```

Will put all output to this text file but this:

```
FOR /F %%i in (C:\Users\c1921\Test\Datapoints\!$MyVar!.txt) DO (
set "$UnitID=%%i"
)
```

Reads every line into a variable. Can I somehow use delims and tokens to only get the numbers?

**Edit:**

I thought this might be possible going off of an answer on this question: [Windows Batch file to echo a specific line number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701910/windows-batch-file-to-echo-a-specific-line-number)

The file I have on occassion might not have a number between the words for example:

```
handled
check
219276
control
219274
co
219268
```

This should not happen often, but I'd like to make sure I can avoid this when it does.

Comment: Why don't you use PowerShell or write a small console C# application to do it for you?

Comment: I don't know what PowerShell is, but I have a batch file that runs curl. Since I can't get libcurl to run on my computer I can't use C# or C++.

Comment: @riaandelange I just read a little bit about Powershell and this looks like exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /r /b /c:"[0-9]" "c:\somewhere\file.txt"') do echo %%a
```

This uses `findstr` to filter the input file with a regular expresion , returning only lines that start with a number

Comment: Wow it is possible! I'm guessing if I substitute `[0-9]` with `[a-z]` I can get the lines without numbers separately! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

```
FINDSTR /b "[0-9]" q25003233.txt
```

I used a file named `q25003233.txt` containing your data for my testing.