# Batch to Print specific lines of text to a file

Tags: windows, batch-file

Let me start off by saying I am very new to this, and what little code I have cobbled together I found on this site.

In the end I need a batch that when ran will grab each folder name in a parent dir. and copy it to a text file named label1, label2, ect.

I started with pulling the lines from a directory list in a text file. I can get it to echo the last line to a file using Seth's code from this post
[Windows Batch file to echo a specific line number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701910/windows-batch-file-to-echo-a-specific-line-number)

I made some modifications to try to put it in a loop and now I get nothing out.

If anyone can help me it would be much appreciated. Here is my code so far.

```
    set /a "x=1"
    set /a "lines=91"
    :while1
        if %x% leq %lines% (
        for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('findstr /n .* "Y:\Test\foldernametest.txt"') do (
      set "FullLine=%%a"
      for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%b in ("%%a") do (
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set "LineData=!FullLine:*:=!"
        if "%%b" equ "%1" echo(!LineData!
        echo title=!linedata! > Lable%x%.dat
        set /a "x= x+1"
        endlocal
        goto :while1
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a x=1
set /a lines=91
:while1
    if %x% leq %lines% (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('findstr /n .* "Y:\Test\foldernametest.txt"') do (
    for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%b in ("%%a") do (
      if "%%b" equ "%x%" (
        echo(%%c
        echo title=%%c > Lable%x%.dat
        set /a x= x+1
        goto while1
      )
    )
)
endlocal
```

I'm reasonably sure this will work, as would

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a x=1
set /a lines=91
:while1
    if %x% leq %lines% (
    for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n .* "Y:\Test\foldernametest.txt"') do if %%a==%x% (
    echo(%%b
    echo title=%%b > Lable%x%.dat
    set /a x= x+1
    goto while1
    )
)
endlocal
```

The issue with your code is that `endlocal` terminates a `setlocal` and all of the environment changes that have taken place since the `setlocal` are backed out - the environment is restored to what it was when the `setlocal` was executed.

The consequence is that with your code, you are incrementing `x` (a grand name for a variable) and then the increment is backed out when the `endlocal` is executed.

So - put the entire routine in a `setlocal/endlocal` bracket. This has other advanteages - like if you execute a `setlocal` immediately after `@echo off`, then when the routine terminates, the environment is returned to its original state - it does not accumulate changes (normally additions of variables) as more and more batches are run.

Some of the other changes I've made are cosmetic. the quotes in a `set /a` are superfluous and so is the colon in a `goto` (with the sole exception of `goto :eof`)

Another problem you have was `%1` (meaning "the first parameter to the routine") where you probably meant "%x%".

In the first code fragment, the output of the `findstr` is assigned to `%%a` and the inner `for` assigns that part of the `findstr` before the delimiter to `%%b` and that after to `%%c`. You evidently want to pick the line `%%b` equal to `%x%` so the code makes the comparison and if equal, outputs `%%c` (rest of line) and `title=%%c` to the file made from `Lable` and the line number. (You've spelled `label` incorrectly); then increments `x` and tries again.

The second piece of code is a simplification of the first. The line is read from the file and numbered, then split directly on the colon; `%%a` gets the number, `%%b` the rest of the line, so if `%%a` is the same as the number `%x%` then we want to do something (no quotes required, since `%%a` is a simple numeric string and `x` will also be numeric because it's never assigned to a *string containing separators* or *empty*).

The thing-to-be-done is to echo the line from the file (in `%%b`, bump the line number and start again...

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you for the help and they very detailed explanation, I'm going to read it about 5 more times and see if I understand it then.