# Using for loop to tokenize within a range and sort

Tags: batch-file

My problem: I have a `.txt` file of strings I'd like to sort through and label in the range 1 through 4. I only want to keep items 1 and 2 while deleting 3 and 4. I know I can use `%4` to keep the 0 and 1 tokenized items while deleting 2 and 3, but the trouble is using an if statement while modulating, and doing that over the whole file. The file size will be at least 5000 /n lines long.

Here's the code I've had the most success with so far. I'm using the code I [found in the top comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701910/windows-batch-file-to-echo-a-specific-line-number/27122848) as a base.

```
@echo on
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('findstr /n .* "C:\...\TEXTFILE.txt"') do (
    set "FullLine=%%a"
    for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%b in ("%%a") do (
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set "LineData=!FullLine:*:=!"
        set /a MODVAR = %%b%%2
        if %%b == !MODVAR! >"TEXTFILE.txt" echo(!LineData! 
        endlocal
    )
)
pause
```

This replaces only the text from line 1. I know I said I want line 1 and 2, but I imagine I'd use an `else` statement to get that second line as well. Just need the current code to work before I try that problem.

I've read that it would be easier to use a regex find and replace, but I'd much prefer to find a solution using batch so I can write (get help with) the current code and be done. Rather than copying/pasting possibly multiple times.

Edit: an example of my initial text document is:

```
    aaa
    bbb
    ccc
    ddd
    eee
```

(and so on) where i want to only keep aaa, bbb, and eee

Comment: Well, I would prefer seeing an actual use case, in other words show the example of the input and demonstrate the expected output results.

Comment: It's unclear how your input textfile looks like, please show an example. The code you copied is just for selecting a single line by its line number. But the part `set /a ccc=%%b%%2` looks odd. Btw. You placed the `endlocal` at the wrong place

Comment: @jeb, yeah, I agree, that is a one strange way to set a value to be 1.

Comment: @Gerhard  I editted the endlocal, as well as the set /a var to keep from confusion in the example. my reason for doing that is because i was trying to simplify using modulo in the if statement since I couldn't find another workaround

Comment: still not sure, I understand you. Is it "take two lines, ignore two, take two ignore two ... etc."?

Comment: @Stephan yes that's the pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modulo is great if you want "each n-th line". Especially for "take two, skip two", there is a better way (a logical bitwise AND).

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

(for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /n "^" in.txt') do (
  set /a "modvar=(%%i-1) & 2"
  REM echo %%i, !modvar!,   %%j >con
  if !modvar! == 0 echo(%%j
))>out.txt
```

I also put the whole output to the outfile in one go. That's much faster than opening the file for each line, writing it and closing the file again.

Remove the `REM` for troubleshooting. It shows you what exactly happens with `modvar`.

(Note: this method works for "take N, skip N" only when `N` is a power of two (1,2,4,8,16,...))

Just for completeness, here is how to do it with MODULO:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

(for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /n "^" in.txt') do (
  set /a "modvar=(%%i-1) %% 4"
  REM echo %%i, !modvar!,   %%j >con
  if !modvar! lss 2 echo(%%j
))>out.txt
```

Comment: Nice!! @Stephan.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure from your description of your actual task, so this is my reading of it, your intention is to recreate the lines of a file as another but with lines `3` and `4` omitted.

Here's one possibility, *subject to whether tabs must be preserved*:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
<"input.txt" (
    Set /P "#1="
    Set /P "#2="
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Set /P "=!#1!"<NUL & Echo(
    Set /P "=!#2!"<NUL & Echo(
    EndLocal
    %SystemRoot%\System32\more.com +4
) >"output.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am focusing on the example you gave of line `3` and `4` only.

On the single file as per your example:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "file=C:\...\TEXTFILE.txt"
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('type "!file!" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break ^> "!file!"') do (
         set "line=%%f"
         if "!line:~0,3!" == "[3]" set "line="
         if "!line:~0,3!" == "[4]" set "line="
         if defined line set "line=!line:*]=!"
         if defined line echo(!line!)>>"!file!"
   )
```

Or to loop through all `.txt` files and perform a delete of lines `3` and `4`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (*.txt) do (
    set "file=%%~i"
    for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('type "!file!" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break ^> "!file!"') do (
         set "line=%%f"
         if "!line:~0,3!" == "[3]" set "line="
         if "!line:~0,3!" == "[4]" set "line="
         if defined line set "line=!line:*]=!"
         if defined line echo(!line!)>>"!file!"
   )
)
```

To understand what happens: We type through the file, add line numbers by using `find /v /n` in brackets. i.e each line will append beginning of line `[1]`,`[2]` etc.

Then we match to see if the first 3 characters matches either `[3]` or `[4]` if they do, clear the variable. Then we simply test each time if the variable is defined, if not (in the case for line 3 and 4) we simply skip `echo`ing those lines.

So given your examples of:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
```

I type the file before, to see the content, run the `batch-file` then type the file again to see the results:

[image]

Comment: this works but as stephan put it a better way to phrase the pattern of which lines to print is "print 2 lines skip two lines". That was where I was getting the idea of using a modulo to simplify which lines to print or skip over any x amount of lines