# Read every 5th line using Batch Script

Tags: windows, file-io, batch-file

I want to make a batch program with will display every 5th line of a text file, like line no 1, 6, 11, 16 ....
I tried modifying head.bat code found here: [Windows batch command(s) to read first line from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/130116/395703)

My code is like below:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if [%1] == [] goto usage

SET /a counter=0

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (%1) do (
set /a testcond=(%%counter-1)%4
if "!testcond!"=="0" echo %%a
set /a counter+=1
)

goto exit

:usage
echo Usage: fifth FILENAME

:exit
```

This code is not working. Can you please tell me what is the wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to change one line in your script as follows:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if [%1] == [] goto usage

SET /a counter=0

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (%1) do (
set /a "testcond=(counter-1)%%5"
if "!testcond!"=="0" echo %%a
set /a counter+=1
)

goto exit

:usage
echo Usage: fifth FILENAME

:exit
```

Now the script should work.

Comment: This script is not working. Showing `%5 was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: @chanchal1987: You are right, it wasn't working, but it seems to be now. Please have a look.