# How to get every 3rd line of text file and put it on a separate text file using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to get only the every 3rd line of a text file(Movie.txt) and put it on a separate text file(Title.txt) using batch script(for /f)

Movie.txt

```
 Movie
  Title
  Anime1
Movie
  Title
  Anime2
Movie
  Title
  Anime3
Movie
  Title
  Anime4
```

Title.txt

```
Anime1
Anime2
Anime3
Anime4
```

currently I have no idea how to get the required data... 
I would appreciate any help you can provide. thank you.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471669/read-every-5th-line-using-batch-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set input=yourinput.txt
set output=youroutput.txt
set i=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%l in (%input%) do (
    set /a i=!i!+1
    set /a r=!i!%%3
    if !r!==0 echo %%l>>%output%
)
```

We can use the modulo operator and a line counter. `!i!` contains the *line number* and `!r!` is the *line number modulo 3*. So if `!r!==0` we write the line (`%%l`) into the output file.

Comment: i will try this tomorrow when i got in office.. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "line1="
SET "line2="
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%a IN (
 'findstr /r "." "100lines.txt"'
 ) DO (
 IF DEFINED line1 (
  IF DEFINED line2 (
   ECHO %%a
   SET "line1="
   SET "line2="
  ) ELSE SET line2=y
 ) ELSE SET line1=y
)
GOTO :EOF
```

All you need is to replace the input filename - I have a file named `100lines.txt` that contains 100 different lines of text.

Since a variable's current `defined` status acts on the `run-time` value of the variable, ensure that the two flags are *clear* to start, then for each line of the file,

if `line1` is not defined, set it
otherwise, if `line2` is not defined, set it
otherwise we are on a `*3` line, so regurgitate it and clear the two flags.