# Get the first two string of a text file in batch files

Tags: string, batch-file, cmd

I have a text file that contains data like this but I want to only get the first two strings of the file.
from this:

```
Caption                           
SMI USB DISK USB Device    
Hitachi HTS547550A9E384
```

to this:

```
Caption                      
SMI USB DISK USB Device
```

Comment: I have not tried anything since i have no knowledge about batch scripting @zb226

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/130298/1529709) for a quasi-implementation in batch of the *nix `head` utility.

Answer (score 3):

Very simple:

```
@echo off
3<text.txt (
set /p line1= <&3
set /p line2= <&3
)
Echo %line1%
Echo %line2%
```

Which is how you get the first to lines of a file. To actually **change** the file so it only consists of these two lines use:

```
@echo off
3<text.txt (
set /p line1= <&3
set /p line2= <&3
)
Echo %line1% > text.txt
Echo %line2% >> text.txt
```

**Note:** You have to replace `text.txt` with the name of your file.

Comment: why do i get an error like this? '3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: @user352156 Whoops, accidental spacing

Comment: which spacing? @monacraft

Comment: @user352156 Look at my edited code. It is now functional

Comment: my output is this: ⁌†ഠ䔊䡃⁏獩漠晦മ

Comment: I have tested this on my own computer and it works fine. Double check that you have implemented it correctly

Comment: My script is:
wmic path Win32_LogonSession get LogonId  > D:\logonid.txt

@echo off
3<D:\logonid.txt (
set /p line1= <&3
set /p line2= <&3
)
Echo %line1% > D:\logonid.txt
Echo %line2% >> D:\logonid.txt

Answer (score 0):

If you have powershell, you can make it by

```
powershell -command "& {get-content filename -totalcount n}"
```

Where `n` is the number of lines to display.

Comment: But i don't have powershell

Comment: Have you tried it? What version of Windows you have?

Comment: How am i able to output it to a txt file?

Comment: Use `> filename` (creating new file) or `>> filename`  (adding at the end of (non)existing file)