# Groovy string substitution txt file gives 0

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In the below code I am reading a .txt file and want to write it's content to the variable userId. But when I do `echo "${userId}"` I get 0, how come? The file itself is located in a SVN branch and I am using jenkins pipeline.

```
def userId = bat script: 'for /f "delims=" %%a in (user_id.txt) do echo %%a', returnStdout: true
```

edit: the txt file contains one line of an user id (for example cronaldo)

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge about batch-scripting, but I would bet, it's the newline after the user_id in the text-file.

If you do the batch for loop on the command-line, you see the user-id on one line and afterwards an empty line I think...

You should try to suppress the empty lines in the output...

Answer (score 0):

I think susi is right and you probably get another line than the one you want...
You could try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/130154/702954) and add an exit after the first echo of your loop, so you are sure to just output the first value.

Example batch :

```
@echo off

for /f %%a in (user_id.txt) do (
  echo %%a
  exit /b
)
```

Convert this to an inline version and put that in your Jenkins pipeline and you should be good to go.

Comment: This removes the other line, but it still does not work since I am getting 0 as output. The question is if it even is possible to assign a value from batch to groovy variable?

Comment: depending on what "bat" returns... I didn't found some documentation about the command

Comment: Could you please edit your post and add a sample output of your `user_id.txt` file please ? Also, [Bat documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#bat-windows-batch-script) seems to indicate this `returnStatus` parameter so I'd say you can use it... but I've never tested it...