# Extract first row from each text file in directory subtree

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-10

I have set of 5000 CSV files in tree directory structure.
Every file was first row denoting its enconding, then typical CSV content follows.

```
UTF-8
Key1,"Value 1",
Key2,"Value 2"
etc, etc...
```

How can I quickly collect first row from each file in order to oversee set of their encodings?

I'm trying this with help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7827243/2392157) but I don't clearly understand all syntax nuances of batch file variables so I am getting stuff like `Echo is on.`

```
for /R D:\resources\ %%f in (*.csv) do (
    set /p line1=<%%f
    echo %line1% >> out.txt
)
```

If parts are executed individually (for single file), they work.

I was also trying single-liner

```
for /R D:\resources\ %f in (*.csv) do set /p line1=<%f & echo %line1% >> out.txt
```

but this one put value collected from first file into output from each file.

Comment: You are getting `Echo is on.` because `%line1%` appears empty. Enable [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) as you write *and* read the variable in the same block of code. Finally, change your `echo` command line to `>> out.txt echo(!line1!`.

Comment: @aschipfl - that helped. Would you like to add it as answer? I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is the lack of [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), which is needed when you write *and* read a variable within the same block of code; without it, you are reading the variable value present when parsing the block, so *before* it is executed. Here is the fixed code:

```cmd
@echo off
copy NUL out.txt
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /R "D:\resources" %%g in ("*.csv") do (
    set "line1="
    < "%%~g" set /P line1=""
    >> "out.txt" echo(!line1!
)
endlocal
```

In addition, I quoted all file/directory paths in order to avoid trouble with white-spaces or special characters in them. I also reversed the [redirection syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html), because `echo(!line1! >> "out.txt"` also outputs the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> in front of `>>`. The `(` instead of a <kbd>SPACE</kbd> behind `echo` looks odd but prevents `ECHO is {on|off}.` being returned when the read line in `!line1!` is empty.

By the way, you do not need to prepare an empty output file `out.txt` initially, you can simply redirect the whole `for` loop into the output files once using `>`, given that you put a surrounding pair of parentheses:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
> "out.txt" (
    for /R "D:\resources" %%g in (*.csv) do (
        set "line1="
        < "%%~g" set /P line1=""
        echo(!line1!
    )
)
endlocal
```

---

To do the same directly in command prompt as a single-liner, try this:

```cmd
cmd /V /C (for /R "D:\resources" %g in ("*.csv") do @(set "line1=" ^& ^< "%~g" set /P line1="" ^& echo(!line1!)) ^> "out.txt"
```

Comment: Man... this is greatly qualified answer. This is also how script files packed by tricks of the pro's become difficult to read for recreational scripters. :) I bookmarked this Q/A to return to these techniques next time. Thank you for optimization and its explanation.

Answer (score 0):

[aschipfl's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44354247/extract-first-row-from-each-text-file/44354459#comment75710452_44354247) helped. Adding corrected and completed script for benefit of others:

```
@echo off
copy NUL out.txt
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /R D:\resources\ %%g in (*.csv) do (
  set /p line1=<%%g
  echo !line1! >> out.txt
)
```