# How to read first line from a SQL file using standard windows command line

Tags: batch-file, command-line

Is it possible to read just the first line from a .sql file in the windows command line?

If so, how can I do this - googleing has not come up with a solution that works.

All I have is standard windows command prompt

Comment: What kind of file? A .txt file?

Comment: @Karel-JanMisseghers .sql but it is very larg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a copy of this question;
[Windows batch command(s) to read first line from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130116/windows-batch-commands-to-read-first-line-from-text-file)

Quoting the accepted answer from that ticket;

Here's a general-purpose batch file to print the top `n` lines from a file like the GNU `head` utility, instead of just a single line.

```
@echo off

if [%1] == [] goto usage
if [%2] == [] goto usage

call :print_head %1 %2
goto :eof

REM
REM print_head
REM Prints the first non-blank %1 lines in the file %2.
REM
:print_head
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a counter=0

for /f ^"usebackq^ eol^=^

^ delims^=^" %%a in (%2) do (
        if "!counter!"=="%1" goto :eof
        echo %%a
        set /a counter+=1
)

goto :eof

:usage
echo Usage: head.bat COUNT FILENAME
```

For example:

```
Z:\>head 1 "test file.c"
; this is line 1

Z:\>head 3 "test file.c"
; this is line 1
    this is line 2
line 3 right here
```

It does not currently count blank lines.  It is also subject to the batch-file line-length restriction of 8 KB.

Comment: Note that this code can be put in a batch file, and you can execute the batch file in command line. as shown in the example.

Answer (score 0):

To read just the first line of a (text) file:

```
<file.txt set /p line=
echo %line%
```

This is the easiest solution. Dependent on the content (poison chars), `echo` might fail.